# Xubuntu 16.04.2 Static noise on recordings

Tags: xubuntu, pulseaudio, microphone

I’d be grateful for some help.

I’ve just installed (full installation) Xubuntu 16.04.2.

On Windows, my sound card (HDA Intel) Realtek ALC260, was pretty basic but it worked just fine.
However, on Xubuntu the sound is a mess since installed. The main problem is when recording voice, I got lot of static in the recording.

It sounds like all ports are open. But I just use one mic at the time. I thought maybe the laptop’s internal mic was open, but I can not even find it, and close it.

I’ve tried Audacity’s Recording Tips, and Reducing noise advice, but hasn’t worked.

Also, lower the mic gain, but then I lower the voice as well. And fiddling with PulseAudio control, and Alsa mixer.

It looks a configuration problem, but I can’t figure it out.
I’ve read others similar problems and tried their advice, but they don't work for me.